# Catching Push registry event?

Tags: java-me

Is there any way to know that whether the application has been invoked manually or by push registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PushRegistry.listConnections(true)` returns a `String[]` of registered connections currently being used --- so if this is an empty array, the MIDlet was started manually.

See http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/ under "Discovering Whether a MIDlet Was Push-Activated".

Answer (score 0):

and be care of that if you need information of whether the middlet was runned by alarm, described way is not about it, its only about different push events like incoming connections. here is the quote from http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/

"Note that the PushRegistry API doesn't provide a way to discover whether the MIDlet was activated by an alarm. If that knowledge is important, you must implement your own detection method. One way is to save information, such as the time of launch, in the RMS, then compare the saved time with the current time when the MIDlet is launched"